# How do I get a server to host a private network

Tags: networking, debian, iptables, ip, nic

I am trying to set up a private network.

Box A is connects to a router which is connected to the internet, is a webserver, and is also the router for a private network. Box A is wireless connections only. Boxes B+ and devices A+ are all supposed to be on the private network, without any access to the internet.

I followed this tutorial: http://blog.noviantech.com/2010/12/22/debian-router-gateway-in-15-minutes/#comments. After restarting, the network interfaces weren't working and I was unable to connect to Box A with Box B. I reversed the changes.

I don't really understand networking that well, and part of the confusion stems from changing standards. For example, in the networking resources I'm reading "allow-hotplug" is never mentioned, and the network interfaces have a new naming standard.

So, how can I get Box A to allow Box B onto a private network?

Or alternatively, a link to a modern tutorial that can show me how to do what I need to.

Comment: The directions there look like they should work just fine.  You may need to adjust the device names with whatever names are valid for your system.  Look at the output of `ip link` to see your device names.

Comment: my device names are wlp3s0 and enx000f004fe450. wlp3s0 is supposed to be the private network card and enx000f004fe450 is supposed to be the router connected device.